# I have problem with @Bean WebDriver and How run sevral tests using @Autowrited

Tags: spring, spring-boot, selenium

Please, promt me. The main idea is create project with Selenium + Spring Boot.
I created it, created test#1 and test#2. If I run test#1, it is okay, after test#1 I want to run test#2, but doing it I have a probem with driver. If I am not mistaken, the reason is @Bean, I created WebDriver using @Bean. I think that problem is the Autowrited Bean with WebDriver, Pls tell me, How create Autowrited Bean for several test.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHY4J.png)
My Code:1) WebDriver config with Bean

```
@Configuration
public class WebDriverConfig {
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "browser", havingValue = "chrome")
@Primary
public WebDriver chromeDriver() {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    return new ChromeDriver();
}
```

2)BasePage

```
@Component
public abstract class BasePage {

@Autowired
protected WebDriver driver;
protected final static long WAIT_TIME = 20;

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    PageFactory.initElements(this.driver, this);
}
```

3)My HomePage with test methods

```
@Component
public class HomePage extends BasePage {
@FindBy(xpath = "//a[@class='login_btn circle']")
private WebElement singIn;

@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='login_input1']")
private WebElement inputLogin;

@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='login_input2']")
private WebElement inputPassword;

@FindBy(css = "#login_submit")
private WebElement loginSubmit;

@FindBy(xpath = "//a[.//*[@id='anime_id_17']]")
private WebElement tg;

@FindBy(xpath = "//a[.//*[@id='anime_id_12']]")
private WebElement codeGias;




public HomePage goToHomePage(String url) {
    driver.get(url);
    waitForPageLoadComplete(WAIT_TIME);
    return this;
}

public HomePage goToLogin(String name, String password) {
    singIn.click();
    waitForPageLoadComplete(WAIT_TIME);
    inputLogin.clear();
    inputLogin.sendKeys(name);
    inputPassword.clear();
    inputPassword.sendKeys(password);
    loginSubmit.click();
    waitForPageLoadComplete(WAIT_TIME);
    tg.click();
    waitForPageLoadComplete(WAIT_TIME);
    return this;
}
public HomePage test(){
    waitForPageLoadComplete(WAIT_TIME);
    codeGias.click();
    waitForPageLoadComplete(WAIT_TIME);
    return this;
}
```

4. My BaseTest

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = SpringSelApplication.class)
public class BaseTest {

    protected Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    public WebDriver driver;

    @Autowired
    public ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void teardown() {
        driver.quit();
   }
}
```

Comment: Your driver is a singleton... Now in your `@AfterEach` you do `driver.quit`... What do you think happens with the shared instance of the `WebDriver`. What I suggest you do is ditch your `@Bean` (and the `teardown` method) add `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` to your test class. Spring Boot Test support will autoconfigure a `WebDriver` for you and reset it between tests.

Comment: It sounds really interesting, Arbitrary do you have a sample ? I am very grateful to you for your comment)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following fixes:

1. You don't have to use `@ExtendWith`, the chances are that you're running a reasonably recent version of spring boot and `@SpringBootTest` is already annotated with `@ExtendWith` annotation internally
2. A `BasePage` class, being abstract is not a `@Component` by itself.
3. When using a `@SpringBootTest`, make sure that you pass the class of the configuration that loads the webdriver. Spring boot, when sees a parameter to the `@SpringBootTest` doesn't load the whole application and instead loads whatever the the specified configuration class defines. Also since this way talks about "specific" configuration class to be loaded, it stops obeying the usual component scanning rules, so your web page might not be loaded, after all you're mixing configuration styles (you have both classes annotated with `@Configuration` and those using declarative approach - annotated with `@Component`)
4. Consider using `@ContextConfiguration` instead of `@SpringBootTest` if you have a plain case of configuration loading and don't really load the whole application

Comment: Thank you, you pointed at my mistakes , and I am really grateful to you, Maybe you have some spamle or template, because this direction is new for me and I misunderstand a bit. Thanks away